# Is it possible to remove the white overlay when logging in from sleep in OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, login-screen

As you can see, when unlocking from sleep there is an, in my opinion, intrusive white box surrounding icon and password. Is it possible to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not a *white overlay*, but a real UI element (likely a window without title bar) containing the password box and your avatar. You can click on it without dismissing the password box contents, but if you click outside, they are removed. You can observe similar behavior with a direct `CGSession -switchToUserID` call.

There is no preference for it. Since it's not just a pretty image like the circle around the avatar, it is not easily editable.

Comment: I believe the process responsible is `SecurityAgent`, but I'm not a 100% sure. Its disassembly is painful to read. I'm giving up. Can't be done with sanity intact.

Comment: Alright, I was hoping there would be a texture file stored somewhere in the library that I could just get rid of or replace with a blank image to change it. Thanks the same :)